# CHMOD 777. In terminal, the command to make all changes affect every file and folder?

Tags: chmod

I am typing this:

```
chmod 777 /home/to the destination ...
```

[image]

But all locked and what I want to do is to make all files and folders to have read and write permission without doing each file/folder separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving files a `777` permission is absolute overkill, mind that you give with this your user full access, the user group full access and **all** others. So from a security standpoint this is a horrible solution.

Permissions are octal and each number represents what you can do with the file:

```
Number  Permission Type       Symbol
------------------------------------
0       No Permission         ---
1       Execute               --x
2       Write                 -w-
3       Execute + Write       -wx
4       Read                  r--
5       Read + Execute        r-x
6       Read +Write           rw-
7       Read + Write +Execute rwx
```

So it is definitively enough to give your user full and the group and others limited access (i.e. 755).

To do this recursively you can use the `-R` flag and the `-v` flag to get a verbose output of the action. So the line you search for is:

```
sudo chmod - Rv 755 /path/destination
```

See [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/chmod.1.html) and [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php) for further reading into.

Answer (score 2):

**It should be noted that this is a dangerous thing to do as it effectively removes all permission-based security of all files and subdirectories and will *break* e.g. ssh!**

*If you insist on doing something dangerous,* can recursively make a home directory and all files/subdirectories  read/write by all users on the system with:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/username
```

Comment: @Videonauth Does my edit address your concern?

Comment: It does, thus reversed my downvote.

Comment: Note that `ssh` will cease to work after that command because it _requires_ more restrictive permissions for the `.ssh` folder and the files therein.

Comment: @PerlDuck you are correct and there are potentially more things that could be problems as well.  I was only addressing the original question that was asked. (i.e. how to do it, not if it was a good idea)

Comment: **blihp**  Warn people first if they're about to do something dangerous instead of telling them how to do it. And sometimes it's better to plainly tell people *not do do something!* (edited but not upvoted nor downvoted though I disagree with you)